# submit a form as an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following html in my component, Im trying to generate a form dynamically based on the number of selected elements that can be from 0 to N

```
<form #form="ngForm" id="formGroupExampleInput">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <a class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let selectedApi of selectedApps;let i=index">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="removeFromSelectedApi(i)">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{selectedApi.url}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{selectedApi.method}}</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="{{i}}-users"
            placeholder="number of users" ngModel>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="{{i}}-rpm"
            placeholder="request per minute between all users" ngModel>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let requiredHeader of selectedApi.requiredHeaders; let in=index">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="{{i}}-{{requiredHeader}}"
            placeholder={{requiredHeader}} ngModel>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let requiredParameter of selectedApi.requiredParametersInURL; let in=index">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="{{i}}-{{requiredParameter}}"
              placeholder={{requiredParameter}} ngModel>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedApi.method=='POST' || selectedApi.method=='PUT' || selectedApi.method=='DELETE'">
          <!-- <textarea class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="{{i}}-{{requiredHeader}}" rows=20></textarea> -->
          <textarea  class="form-control"
                rows="5"
                name="{{i}}-body" 
                id="{{i}}-body" 
                placeholder="body" ngModel></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" (click)="onSubmitTest(form)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

when I create new elements and submit the form I get as a result on form.value something like this:

```
0-auth-system: "c"
0-auth-user: "d"
0-auth-user-id: "e"
0-email: "h"
0-module: "g"
0-rpm: "b"
0-task-client-key: "f"
0-users: "a"
1-auth-system: "k"
1-auth-user: "l"
1-auth-user-id: "m"
1-rpm: "j"
1-task-client-key: "n"
1-users: "i"
```

and what I want in fact is an output like the following since it is easier for processing and I dont want to develop code to parse to the previous structure if I can have it as an array:

```
[
 {
  auth-system: "c"
  ,auth-user: "d"
  ,auth-user-id: "e"
  ,email: "h"
  ,module: "g"
  ,rpm: "b"
  ,task-client-key: "f"
  ,users: "a"
},
{
  auth-system: "k"
  ,auth-user: "l"
  ,auth-user-id: "m"
  ,rpm: "j"
  ,task-client-key: "n"
  ,users: "i"
 }
]
```

Anyone knows how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
   <form [formGroup]="myFormUnit" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <table class="table table-lessons table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Field A</th>
            <th>Field B</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of myFormUnit.get('items').controls; let i=index" [formGroup]="item">
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control lablel border-less" [attr.id]="'name'+i" formControlName="name"
                     disabled="disabled">
              <input type="number" class="form-control hidden" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden"
                     [attr.id]="'grade_list'+i" formControlName="grade_list"
                     style="visibility: hidden;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" [attr.id]="'min_grade'+i" formControlName="min_grade">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" [attr.id]="'max_grade'+i" formControlName="max_grade">
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

and ts file is :

```
 myFormUnit: FormGroup;
  protected onInitializeComponent() {
    this.myFormUnit = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }
  private fillUnitform(input?: any) {
    this.myFormUnit = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array(
        []
        // [this.buildItem(null, 'lesson'), this.buildItem(null, 'lesson')]
      )
    });
    this.gradeListItems.forEach(item => {
      if (item.value !== "12") {
        const tmp: Array<any> = this.gridData.data;
        tmp.forEach(element => {
          if (element.lesson_type === item.value) {
            item.value = element.num_unit;
          }
        });
        const fbb = this.myFormUnit.get("items") as FormArray;
        if (item.value !== "12") {
          const newItem = {
            name: item.text,
            grade_list: item.value,
            min_grade: item.min_grade,
            max_grade: item.max_grade
          };
          if (input) {
            // if (input.length > 0)

            input.forEach((element: any) => {
              if (element.grade_list === item.value) {
                newItem.min_grade = element.min_grade;
                newItem.max_grade = element.max_grade;
              }
            });
          }

          fbb.push(this.fb.group(this.buildItem(newItem)));
        }
      }
    });
  }
  buildItem(item: any) {
    return {
      name: new FormControl(item.name),
      grade_list: new FormControl(item.grade_list),
      min_grade: new FormControl(item.min_grade),
      max_grade: new FormControl(item.max_grade)
    };
  }

submit(){
        this.myFormUnit.value.items.forEach(
          (item): any => {
            if (item.min_grade || item.max_grade) {
              grade_list.push({
                grade_list: item.grade_list,
                min_grade: item.min_grade,
                max_grade: item.max_grade
              });
            }
          }
        );

}
```

Comment: mosi98, you needn't create a formGroup with a formArray, you can use a formArray directly -see my answer-

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

[Check out this site](https://blog.karmacomputing.co.uk/angular-6-dynamically-add-rows-reactive-forms-how-to/)

I'm sure it'll give you an idea if you read it carefully

Comment: While sharing a link might be helpful, it's not an answer. Answers should contain an explanation instead of pure links or code

Comment: correct but if the link is followed it'll provide an answer, the link directs to a tutorial that explains in detail. What is the point of me explaining it if the link already does? Repetition is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

@mosi98, you needn't create a formGroup with property items, and "items" was a formArray

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
  <!--see that, form is a FormArray, but we use [formGroup] too-->
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let group of form.controls;let i=index">
        <div [formGroup]="group">
            <input formControlName="name"/>
            <input formControlName="grade_list"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr/>
  <pre>
   {{form?.value|json}}
  </pre>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items=[
  {name: "c",grade_list: "d",min_grade: "e",max_grade: "h"},
  {name: "c",grade_list: "d",min_grade: "e",max_grade: "h"},
  {name: "c",grade_list: "d",min_grade: "e",max_grade: "h"}]

  form:FormArray=new FormArray(this.buildForm(this.items))

  //return an array of FormGroup
  buildForm(items:any[]):FormGroup[]
  {
    return items.map(x=>this.buildItem(x))
  }
  //return a formGroup
  buildItem(item: any):FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(item.name),
      grade_list: new FormControl(item.grade_list),
      min_grade: new FormControl(item.min_grade),
      max_grade: new FormControl(item.max_grade)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: the items in the array are dynamic, they can be from 1 to n<100, so I cannot create a class like that for items

Comment: MBG, the "items" in my example is a "easy way" to give some values, In "real world" I supouse the data becomes from a service. In the subscribe of the service you can call to this.buildForm using the array of object that you receive. The only thing I want to remark is that if you has an array of object, you can mannage the FormArray itself

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the input names as array like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<div *ngFor="let selectedApi of selectedApps;let i=index">
<input type="text" [attr.name]="'obj['+i+'][users]'">
<input type="text" [attr.name]="'obj['+i+'][module]'">
<input type="text" [attr.name]="'obj['+i+'][email]'">
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

So you get an array of objects.